# Sharing a pool of Selenium instances with asyncio

Tags: python, selenium, python-asyncio

I have a pool of selenium instances created this way:

```
selenium_instances = [
webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe"),
webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe"),
webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe")]
```

Then I have an asyncio event that can be called at random times.

I would like it to take the first available instance of `selenium_instances` and lock it until it is done, if there is none available I would like it to wait for a maximum of 5 minutes for one available.

I trying googling asyncio lock but did not really understand how to do this in Python.

What would be the correct way to do this?